# Do we create difference projects when implementing micro services architecture in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, microservices

I am confused with microservice architecture. I am not able to understand how to implement the microservice architecture in spring. In spring we use `@RestController` for Rest API. Let's say we have two rest controller like below

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserService {
// this class will hanlder operations related to user
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/role")
public class RoleService {
// this class will hanlder operations related to role
}
```

Both rest controllers belong to one single project. Can we say our above structure is microservices? Or we have to create two projects one is `UserServiceProject` and another one is `RoleServiceProject`. In `UserServiceProject` we create Rest Controller for rest API of User operations. In `RoleServiceProject` we create Rest Controller for rest API of Role Operations.

As microservices architecture says each service should be independently deployable. From this definition can we say that if we have 2 services we need to create two projects so that both projects can be independently deployable.

Please also note both services share the same database and also there is a relationship between User and Role.

Comment: Im using .net web api, but yes I create a seperate Project for each service. Each service is its own self-contained program that can do certain, specific tasks. Then, when everything is its own project you can deploy each service independently to its own server, or deploy everything to 1 server with multiple virtuals running each service. There are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: @victor If we create multiple projects for each service and how we will handle dependency like User has the relationship with the role.  We want to provide an operation like getUserRole(id), Then how we will handle this case. In which service/project this operation will add?

Comment: I would say that the User Service should be able to do all things related to User table/ User functionality. I would not have a Role Service that just determines a users role in your system. That would be a service that is so small that its benefit is outweighed by the inherent complexity of a microservice system. Something like that is called a Nanoservice: "[A] nanoservice is an anti-pattern where a service is too fine grained. [A] nanoservice is a service whose overhead (communications, maintenance etc.) outweighs its utility."

Comment: @victor I understood. Thank you for your valuable comments.

Comment: check out Martin Fowler for a bunch more resources on microservices. https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html

There are a lot of real good talks about microservices on youtube that really helped me when I was first starting off with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microservices separation needs thinking from functional perspective(Z-axis scaling) rather than technical perspective. When you say each individual service, that may not mean every api should be places as a different service, it can be thought as group of api which constitute a logical service to the user, that can be separately developer/tested/deployed/managed.
When you have monolithic apps which do everything like user management, inventory management, order management etc. it makes sense to break these modules into microservices so that the complete flow is build by these services interacting to each other. Also Think from the aspect of scaling, Do you need to scale the individual services depending on the requirement.

But in your case user management and role management may not be of big use when exposed as two different services. user, roles may be co-existing entities which share same database and functionality to achieve.